# Read Mapping Xml file generated by FluentNHibernate API

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

How can I read mapping Xml file  generated by Fluent NHibernate API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you configure FluentNhibernate

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.Configure();
PersistenceModel persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel ();
persistenceModel.Configure (config);
```

You can use

```
persistenceModel.WriteMappingsTo (path);
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying this, but its not writing, its not failing, infact it's not doing anything. what should I do? thanks.